# Ionic4 Native Geolocation doesn't ask for permission Android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm desperate.

I've build an application on Ionic4 and iOS and Android and some **Ionic native** libraries.

I'm using the `Geolocation` Native API and it's working perfectly on iOS.

My problem is with **Android**. If I ran `ionic cordova run android --livereload` the location works perfectly but if I build --prod, nothing happens. It doesn't prompt for the permission to use your location, nothing... It doesn't even show the loading spinner. Has someone experienced something similar? I've also tested using the GoogleMaps API, no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could you please give some more details regarding your issue?

Also as a quick workaround could you please by wrapping your geolocation code inside `this.platform.ready()` listner, for better debugging of your issue.

Comment: Hey thank you! After you said that I noticed that I have a platform.ready() on the app.component and another one at the component that loads the map. I think that was screwing things up. I've removed the second one and everything works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: You are most welcome. Please give an upvote if the answer really helped you. :)